# Sorting list of hashes in Perl with sort

Tags: perl

```
   use Data::Dumper;
   
   sub byage {
           $age{$a} <=> $age{$b};  # presuming numeric
       }
          
  my @class = ( { student => "student1", age => 33, },
{ student => "student2", age => 66, }, 
{ student => "student3", age => 44, }, );
  my @sortedclass = sort byage @class;
  
  print Dumper(@class);
  print Dumper(@sortedclass);
```

I am trying to follow perldoc Sort examples.
I want to sort a list of hashes, based on at least in perldoc example, value of age key.
Not certain what I am doing wrong.
The above does not appear to sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you should be doing is putting `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of your code so you can get the warning that there is no hash `%age`.

What you want is to compare the `age` values in each of `$a` and `$b`.

```
sub byage {
    $a->{age} <=> $b->{age};  # presuming numeric
}

my @class = (
    { student => "student1", age => 33, },
    { student => "student2", age => 66, },
    { student => "student3", age => 44, },
);
my @sortedclass = sort byage @class;
```

Comment: Took out warnings because of messages. What data structure are perldocs referencing with regards to $age{b}

Comment: "Took out warnings because of messages." That sounds like a terrible idea. You wanted to solve a problem in your code so you removed the code that was pointing out problems in your code :-)

Comment: @DaveCross Test script. Trying to figure out what data structure perldoc was referring to. Thought a my was missing from sample code.

Comment: "Took out warnings because of messages."  Those messages would have led you to help solve your problem.  Those messages would have told you that there is no hash `age` to be used in your original `byage` function.  As to "What data structure are perldocs referencing with regards to $age{b}" I don't know what you're referring to specifically.  Perhaps if you pointed at a specific place in the perldoc that we could look at.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment:

> What data structure are perldocs referencing with regards to $age{b}

I think you've been looking at this entry in the Perl FAQ - [How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)?) It contains this example:

> ```
> my @keys = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
> ```

The data structure the sort expression is referring to is the hash called `%hash`.

When you borrowed that example for your own code, you changed it to this:

```
sub byage {
  $age{$a} <=> $age{$b};  # presuming numeric
}
```

This is looking for a hash called `%age`. But nowhere in your code is there a hash called `%hash`. You have an array called `@class`.

There are a few misunderstandings here, but I think the most important one is this. The FAQ you were looking at is about sorting a hash[*] ("How do I sort a hash...?") but you want to sort a list[**] ("Sorting list of ..."). List (or arrays) and hashes are rather different data structures, so it's going to be unhelpful trying to use a sorting technique meant for a hash when you're trying to sort an array.

The `sort()` function sorts a list. You give it one list and it returns another. In the FAQ example, the input list is the keys of a hash (produced with `keys %hash`) and the output list is those same keys sorted in a different order. In your actual problem, the input is an array of hash references and the output is a list of those hash references in a different order.

When you write a sort expression (or, in your case, a sort subroutine), you get two elements of the input list in `$a` and `$b` and you return a value indicating how those two values should be sorted. In the FAQ example, `$a` and `$b` will be keys and you can use those keys to look into the hash (`$hash{$a}` and `$hash{$b}`) and get the associated values. In your problem, `$a` and `$b` will be two of the hash references from your input array. You can look up the "age" key in reach of those (`$a->{age}` and `$b->{age}`) to get the values you want to compare.

As others have pointed out. Adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code is always a good idea. Fixing the problems they show you is an even better one.

[*] Pedantically, you can't sort a hash. What the FAQ code is actually doing is producing a sorted list of hash keys.
[**] Although you actually have an array, not a list.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort different examples:
 # sort using explicit subroutine name
sub byage {
    $age{$a} <=> $age{$b};  # presuming numeric
}

Comment: @PaulM: Ok, but that doesn't invalidate any of my discussion.